# I received error when trying to send a message

Tags: android

```
send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //URI uri=uri.parse("sms://+919500518057");
    sendSms("9500518057","message");
    //startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("sms:"+ "+919500518057")));
    }

    private void sendSms(String phno, String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("PhoneNumber",phno);
        Log.v("MEssage", message);
        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Object.class), 0);
        SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phno, null, message, pi, null);
    }
});
```

In manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

I received error as following:

The method getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int) in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, Intent, int)
in the manifest file i put the following code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this method from your main:

```
private void sendSMS() {
        SMSSend smsSend = new SMSSend();

        smsSend.execCommand();
    }
```

then the below two classed will be responsible for sending SMS.

```
public class SMSSend {

    private final String CLASS_NAME = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private final static String SEND_SMS_FAILURE = "Send SMS command executed and status is failure";
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String messageText;

    /**
     * constructor is defined.
     * 
     * @param CommandProcessor
     *            cmdProcessor
     */
    public SMSSend() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * execCommand method
     * 
     * It is an overridden here and declared in CommandHandler (base class)
     */
    public void execCommand() {
        try {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    sendSMS();
                }
            }.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    /**
     * sendSMS method
     * 
     * It retrieves the command parameters and sends the sms.
     * 
     * @param Command
     *            command
     * @return Status
     */
    private void sendSMS() {
        try {
            SMSSendHelper smsHelper = new SMSSendHelper();
            phoneNumber = "0123456789";
            messageText = "Message Text smaple";
            if (null == phoneNumber || phoneNumber.length() < 2) {
            } else {
                smsHelper.sendSMS(phoneNumber, messageText);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }

    }

}




/**
 * SMSSend class
 * 
 * It is responsible for sending SMSs.
 *  
 */
public class SMSSendHelper {
    private final String CLASS_NAME = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    private String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    private PendingIntent sentPI;
    private BroadcastReceiver sentReceiver;
    private BroadcastReceiver deliveredReceiver;
    private PendingIntent deliveredPI;
    private static final int SMS_LENGHT = 160;
    private static String status = "";

    /**
     * Constructor is defined
     * 
     * @param Status
     *            smsstatus
     */
    public SMSSendHelper() {
        sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ConfigClass.getAppContext(), 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

        deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ConfigClass.getAppContext(),
                0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
        sentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    try {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            lock.notifyAll();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    setSendSMSSataus("SMS Sent");
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    try {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            lock.notifyAll();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    setSendSMSSataus("Generic failure");
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    try {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            lock.notifyAll();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    setSendSMSSataus("No service");
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    try {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            lock.notifyAll();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    setSendSMSSataus("Null PDU");
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    try {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            lock.notifyAll();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    setSendSMSSataus("Radio off");
                    break;
                default:
                    try {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            lock.notifyAll();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;

                }
                ConfigClass.getAppContext().unregisterReceiver(sentReceiver);
            }
        };
        // ---when the SMS has been sent---
        ConfigClass.getAppContext().registerReceiver(sentReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(SENT));

        deliveredReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    break;
                }
                ConfigClass.getAppContext().unregisterReceiver(
                        deliveredReceiver);
            }
        };

        ConfigClass.getAppContext().registerReceiver(deliveredReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
    }

    /**
     * setSendSMSSataus method
     * 
     * @param setSendSMSSataus
     *            currentSataus
     */
    public static void setSendSMSSataus(String currentSataus) {
        status = currentSataus;

    }

    /**
     * getSendSMSSataus method
     * 
     * @return String status
     */
    public String getSendSMSSataus() {
        int i = sentReceiver.getResultCode();
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * sendSMS method
     * 
     * @param String
     *            phoneNumber
     * @param String
     *            message
     * @return Status
     */
    public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        if (message == null) {
            message = " ";
        }

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

        if (message.length() > SMS_LENGHT) {
            sendLongSMS(sms, message, phoneNumber);
        } else {
            Log.d("E++++D",phoneNumber+"======>>>>>SOS");

            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
        }
        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.wait();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void sendLongSMS(SmsManager sms, String message, String phoneNumber) {
        ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
        int numParts = parts.size();
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numParts; i++) {
            sentIntents.add(sentPI);
            deliveryIntents.add(deliveredPI);
        }

        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentIntents,
                deliveryIntents);
    }

    private Object lock = new Object();
}
```

Comment: This provides alternative code to accomplish the task, but does not solve the error in the question

Comment: but Raghav, its a-lot better than the else, as we can send as many message as we want from it using Thread and also its increase the efficiency of our application...isn't it?

Comment: You will still be limited by the 100sms/hour limit on the newer devices. And while the code may work well, it still doesn't answer the specific problem the OP was having, even if it accomplishes the same task.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong `this`. Swap this:

```
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Object.class), 0);
```

for this:

```
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(YourActivity.this, 0, new Intent(YourActivity.this, Object.class), 0);
```

Right now you're using the `OnClickListener.this`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, new Intent(mContext, Object.class), 0);
```

And in your global variables add:

```
private Context mContext;
```

And initialize it in onCreate() after the super call using:

```
mContext = this;
```

By using only `this` while creating the `PendingIntent`, you're not referring to the current instance of your `Activity`. You're referring to the current instance of the `OnClickListener` inner class

Answer (score 0):

I am using this for sending Message:--

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{        

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);     
}
```

Comment: will it ask any prompt? I clicked the send button but no response

Answer (score 0):

PendingIntent requires a Context as first parameter. Inside an activity you can pass the activity context to the method using `PendingIntent.getActivity(this, ..)`.

However this doesn't work in an `setOnClickListener` (like you did). Inside the OnclickListener  `this` references the `setOnClickListener` (which isn't a valid context object) and not the activity.

If you want to pass the activity to the `getActivity` you can use `PendingIntent.getActivity(<NameOfYourActivity>.this, ..)`

e.g. `PendingIntent.getActivity(MyActivity.this, ..)`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {        
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);                
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
    }
```